# Best Practice for variation with animated type

Tags: typography, animation

I am a designer that does not work with much motion graphics. Since I am at a startup I wear many hats. I have created a 30 second animation for our company that explains our product. The type animates in and I was using only two different variations:

- A swipe for the first and last titles that look alike (Call that Style A)
- A slide up for all of the typography in 3 scenes. This explained a 3 step process of our product. (Call that Style B)

I figured two variations of animating-in type was enough for a 30 second video and it made sense to group them. However I received feedback from a non-designer that Style B seemed too repetitive and they wanted to see another animation.

I think that may be a bit much and they'd lose a sense of connectivity and consistency. I think it makes sense that all three steps in Style B shared the same animation.

I'd like to see if there's any motion designers that have opinions on the matter so I can make an informed design decision. My gut tells me I have it right but my expertise is not in motion graphics.

Comment: Can we see a video?

Comment: As is, I believe this question is opinion based/too broad and should be closed. If you provided the video I can see it being on topic as not opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you my personal feedback as a designer who has watched ***way*** too many lunch n learn PowerPoint and Keynote presentations, both product specific and general technical considerations types, whilst working in the architectural field: any such type animation should be fast enough to not induce a sensation of frustration waiting for all the type to resolve/arrive, and should also be almost unnoticeable once the graphic language has been absorbed - which tends to imply consistency throughout - meaning your concept in which start/end titles have one style, and all others have a single consistent other style is spot-on IMHO.